# In MySQL, query of a word also matches words with special characters

Tags: mysql, sql, special-characters

The following query is supposed to match all comments containing 'testa', but it matches 'testä', as shown below:

```
mysql> select comment from document where comment='testa';
+---------+
| comment |
+---------+
| testä   |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

How to do an exact match only for the string 'testa', so that it doesn't show results for its matching special character?

Comment: This is collation-dependent. Specify collation which must be used during the compare explicitly, like `select comment from document where comment='testa' COLLATE utf8MB4_bin;`

Comment: @ManojAgarwal Please check my answer. Please let me know does it serve your purpose or not. Best wishes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have a solution for you. You can use `convert(column_name using latin1)`. Please check my code below=>

```
CREATE TABLE document(
 comment  varchar(20)
);

Insert INTO document
SELECT 'testä';

Insert INTO document
SELECT 'testa';

select comment from document where convert(comment using latin1)='testa';
```

if you want to use `COLLATE` then MySql version should be 8.0 as Akina mentioned in the description.

**Note :**  Please check the link [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=db503c5393b04af037a7b1ab758a8dac)

Comment: Yes, it works from sql prompt. I am using Perl DBD::mysql cpan module to execute such database queries.  If I try to execute the same query using this module, I get the following  error: "DBD::mysql::st execute failed: COLLATION 'utf8mb4_bin' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'", and same query works fine at sql prompt.  What is needed to make it work through this module?